# Snowflake Result Cache

Tags: caching, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a questions regarding the Result Cache. In one of the snowflake documentation, It is given that to use the Result cache the Role has to be same even though Users are different. However when i tried with different Roles and User i was still able to access the Result Cache, Can you confirm my understanding - Any Roles that has access to the Object can reuse the result Cache though it is not same.

My Experiment:

User 1 with Role1 executed - select * from emp;

User 2 with Role2 executed the same query - select * from emp; It used fetched the result from Cache without using the Virtual Warehouse.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Snowflake documentation, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html#retrieval-optimization, most queries require that the role accessing result cache must have access to all underlying data that produced the result cache.  The one exception noted is the `SHOW` command result cache can only be accessed using the same role.  This may be the cause for the exception noted in the documentation that you've shared, although it is less clear.

Comment: @ Mike - Thanks, it was little confusing. The image is pasted was the documentation from the mindtickle - https://snowflakeuniversity.mindtickle.com/.

Answer (score -1):

The cache can not be served without any virtual Warehouse.

We require to compute (virtual Warehouse/cross virtual ) to process or preserve the cached data in there local disk.

"These are available across virtual warehouses, so query results returned to one user is available to any other user on the system who executes the same query, provided the underlying data has not changed."

for more detail [link](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Caching-in-Snowflake-Data-Warehouse)

Comment: I believe the OP was only talking about result cache, not warehouse cache.

Comment: I think your comment of cache cannot be served without any virtual warehouse may not be right. When you run a query, the result of that is cached in the metadata repository. And anything that comes from the metadata repository is not charged for compute since it does not use warehouse. However, SSD cache is a different thing and that is lost if the virtual warehouse is stopped. Ideally if the user used the same role with which the query was run earlier, the result will come from the result cache. And my understanding is that if role is different, that cache is not available to the user.

Comment: Rajib  we  have below  three way to cache   Result Cache:  Which holds the results of every query executed in the past 24 hours. These are available across virtual warehouses, so query results returned to one user is available to any other user on the system who executes the same query, provided the underlying data has not changed.

Comment: Remote Disk:  Which holds the long term storage.  This level is responsible for data resilience, which in the case of Amazon Web Services, means 99.999999999% durability.  Even in the event of an entire data centre failure.

Comment: Local Disk Cache:  Which is used to cache data used by SQL queries.  Whenever data is needed for a given query it's retrieved from the Remote Disk storage, and cached in SSD and memory.

Comment: Logically for any cash : we required the result set to be stored in memory or disk and this this ie present only at virtual Warehouse / cross virtual in snow flack .